# Django rest-framework server timed out (ConnectionError)

Tags: python, django, mongodb, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm developing a django-rest framework system with a mongodb backend. When I execute the command -

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get the following error text:

```
raise ConnectionError("Cannot connect to database %s :\n%s" % (alias, e))
mongoengine.connection.ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database default :
timed out
```

Here are the relevant codes for the project 'mysite':

settings.py

```
import os
from mongoengine import connect
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


SECRET_KEY = '<xxx>'


DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

MONGO_DATABASE_NAME = 'mydb'
MONGO_HOST = '<xxxx>'
MONGO_PORT = 27017
connect(MONGO_DATABASE_NAME, host=MONGO_HOST, port=MONGO_PORT)




INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'mysite',
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'




DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy'
    }
}



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True




STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

models.py

```
class mydata(object):
    def __init__(self, phone_no, name, address, categories):
        self.phone_no = phone_no
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
    self.categories = categories
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import mydata

class mydataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    phone_no = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    address = serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=200)
    categories = serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=200)

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        if instance:
            instance.phone_no = attrs.get('phone_no', instance.phone_no)
            instance.name = attrs.get('name', instance.name)
            instance.address = attrs.get('address', instance.address)
            instance.categories = attrs.get('categories', instance.categories)
            return instance

        return mydata(attrs.get('phone_no'),attrs.get('name'),attrs.get('address'),attrs.get('categories'))
```

views.py

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from pymongo import Connection
from models import mydata
from serializers import mydataSerializer

@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET'])
def pg(request):
    #connect to our local mongodb
    db = Connection('localhost',27017)
    #get a connection to our database
    dbconn = db.mydb
    mydbCollection = dbconn['mydb']

    if request.method == 'GET':
        #get our collection
        pdata = []
        for r in mydbCollection.find():
            temp = mydata(r["phone_no"],r["name"],r["address"],r["categories"])
            pdata.append(temp)
        serializedList = mydataSerializer(pdata, many=True)
        return Response(serializedList.data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^mydata/$', 'mysite.views.pg', name = 'mydata'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I have created a database called mydb with a collection inside it called mydbCollection with the data required. What is causing this error?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a password for the database to connect to ?
and not sure why the error  is <strong> mongoengine.connection.ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database default</strong>
is the database name correct too ?

Comment: Yeah there's no password, database name is correct as well